# Second DIMM installed in motherboard stops video card from showing image

Tags: video, memory, power-supply

I have a [Powerspec B800](http://www.powerspec.com/systems/system_specs.phtml?selection=B800) that had a GeForce 8400GS PCIe 256MB card.  I wanted to upgrade to a card with HDMI so I can send a feed to my TV.  I purchased an EVGA GeForce 210 1024MB DDR3.  I installed the card and had video, but once Windows loaded there was no picture...the monitor (VGA or HDMI) was getting a signal (meaning it wouldn't go into powersave mode), but no picture - just a black screen. Checked the EVGA site, which suggested removing a DIMM.  Bingo - picture works.

Since I obviously want 4GB of RAM instead of 2GB, I did some research that seemed to indicate the power supply needed to be upgraded.  Purchased a new 750Watt supply with (4) 12V rails at 18A each.  Installed both DIMMs - same issue, no picture.  Remove a DIMM and the video works.  The EVGA GeForce 210 does not have a power plug - it gets all its power from the PCIe slot.

I have tried swapping DIMMs and slots, so it isn't an issue with the RAM itself.

I have read that there are some BIOS settings to allocate power to different slots and PCIe, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because this is purely speculation. if you are using 32 bit windows you can only address up to 4GB of RAM (including video RAM). However in my experience it will just show you 3 GB as available RAM and not mess with the video RAM. I don't know may have nothing to do with it but I figured I would add it anyway.

Comment: If the site recommended removing a DIMM, they must have a reason for recommending it.  Have they done any research into why that is the solution.  Did they narrow this down to a certain motherboard, driver with Windows, monitor brand, or combination of these things?

Answer (score 0):

If EVGA won't provide a better solution, return the card as not fit for purpose and buy a  different make.